# Northscale memcached ram usage problem?

Tags: memcached

We started using memcached on the test server for our social media project and having some problems on ram usage.

We have created a cluster with 1 server node running with just 1 cache bucket sized 128 mb but when we check memcached.exe ram usage from the task manager it' s ram usage rises continously 1mb per second.

Any workaround on this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using our 1.0.3 product (the current version of our Memcached server) there is a known issue where deleting the default bucket causes a memory leak.  Can you let me know whether you deleted the default bucket?

Also, we just released beta 4 of our 1.6.0 product which has support for both Membase buckets as well as Memcached buckets.  I would certainly appreciate you taking a look and trying it out.  I know it has fixed the memory leak issue.

Thanks so much.

Perry

Comment: yes, that's exactly what we've done. just created the default bucket and everything is normal. thank you!